# Keybinding to zoom in/out of flash widget

Tags: browser, flash, accessibility

I'm looking for a keybinding to zoom in/zoom out of flash widgets similar to Ctrl++ and Ctrl+- on webbrowsers default aka increasing font size. I'm aware of the right click option, but from time to time this option is not active for a flash widget.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a keybinding for this in adobe's flash player.  And as you've noticed, the right-click option can be disabled by the widget author.

Your OS may offer what you're looking for though: on OS X, in the System Preferences -> Accessibility panel, you can enable "Zoom" which allows the user to zoom the entire display using <kbd>control</kbd>+Scroll-up / <kbd>control</kbd>+Scroll-down to zoom-in or -out. You can also change which key is used to trigger this behavior (<kbd>Alt</kbd> for example.).

Windows 8.1 allows something similar in the Settings Charm -> Change PC Settings -> Ease of Access -> Magnifier, though it's a little clunkier in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tipps. So the best way would be ask the author of crappy flash widet, to build it with HTML5 and CSS in future.